# How map response types in Angular2

Tags: angular

I have an interface class for my apis for reuse.

```
export interface BaseResponse<T> {
status : string;
message : string;
data : Array<T>;
```

}

This has a data property which contains the response. Its always in same place and always an array. If 1, list of 1, if 0, list of none.

I'm trying to map the response so that only the data element is returned to the calling service. i.e.

```
/* GET whose name contains search term */
searchItem(term: string): Observable<Item> {
  if (!term.trim()) {
    // if not search term, return empty array.
    // let s = new BaseResponse<Item>()
    return of();
  }
  let response = this.http.get<BaseResponse<Item>>(`${this.baseItemUrl}?name=${term}`).pipe(
    map(x => x.data)
    tap(x => x.data.length ?
       this.log(`found matching "${term}"`) :
       this.log(`no matching "${term}"`)),
    catchError(this.handleError<BaseResponse<Item>>('searchItem'))
  );
}
```

Error this throws up is

```
Type 'Observable<BaseResponse<Item> | Item[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Item>'.
  Type 'BaseResponse<Item> | Item[]' is not assignable to type 'Item'.
    Type 'BaseResponse<Item>' is missing the following properties from type 'Item': id, namets(2322)
```

This makes sense, but I don't know how to correctly map the type from BaseResponse to the data property on base reponse and return [T]?

Alternatively, this may be the wrong place to do this so happy to change approach.

Comment: function doesn't return anything after that first `if`

Comment: You seem to have included incomplete code since you're not returning `response`.

Answer (score 0):

Things are things missing in your `searchItem` function.

First, it doesn't look like your function signature is correct, from your post, I'd imagine your return type should be `Obersavable<Array<Item>>`

```
searchItem(term: string): Observable<Array<Item>> {
```

Your branch on the `!term.trim()` if statement should return an empty array.

```
  if (!term.trim()) {
    // if not search term, return empty array.
    // let s = new BaseResponse<Item>()
    return of([]);
  }
```

The rest was almost there, but missing the return of the `response`. Also updated the `map` function to return an empty array if no `data` as I don't know what your response type would look like.

Complete example

```
  /* GET whose name contains search term */
searchItem(term: string): Observable<Array<Item>> {
  if (!term.trim()) {
    // if not search term, return empty array.
    // let s = new BaseResponse<Item>()
    return of([]);
  }
  let response = this.http.get<BaseResponse<Item>>(`${this.baseItemUrl}?name=${term}`).pipe(
    map(x => x.data || [])
    tap(x => x.data.length ?
       this.log(`found matching "${term}"`) :
       this.log(`no matching "${term}"`)),
    catchError(this.handleError<BaseResponse<Item>>('searchItem'))
  );
  return response;
}
```